# How do you get djangorestframework to return xml using format suffix?

Tags: python, xml, django, django-rest-framework

I can get djangorestframework to return json via a format suffix .json, but not return xml via a .xml suffix

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/rooms/.json

[
{
id: 1,
timestamp: "2013-12-05T04:27:42Z",
topic: "important one"
},
{
id: 2,
timestamp: "2013-12-05T04:27:49Z",
topic: "important two"
},
{
id: 3,
timestamp: "2013-12-05T04:27:55Z",
topic: "important three"
},
{
id: 4,
timestamp: "2013-12-05T04:28:01Z",
topic: "important four"
},
{
id: 5,
timestamp: "2013-12-05T06:43:38Z",
topic: "another great stimulating topic"
}
]


http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/rooms/.xml

{
detail: "Not found"
}
```

Could anyone tell me what I did wrong, b/c the REST api is clearly working...thanks!

Comment: Any relevant code? urls.py and view are particularly interesting.

Comment: Why dont you add codes of models and views so any one can get knowledge

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the `XMLRenderer` which is not enabled by default.

To do this in settings have something like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.XMLRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
  )
}
```

To set renderers at the view level use the `render_classes` attribute.

Take a look at [the Renderers documentation](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers).

**Update**: It occurs to me the above is only half the answer. You'll also need to add the `xml` [format suffix, as documented here](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes).

I hope that helps.

Comment: You are the man. Thank you very much.  It does seem a bit odd to me that xml would not be enabled by default, but this is a wonderful framework.  I get more done in 1/10th the time compared to the java way.

Comment: Probably accurate in 2013, but you'll have too look at Revi Gadila answer in 2017.

Answer (score 3):

Now `XMLRenderer` is available as third-party package.

```
$ pip install djangorestframework-xml
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_xml.renderers.XMLRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
}
```

Full [django-rest-framework-xml Docs](http://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-xml/)