# How to get xml format in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, xml, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get xml format in Django Rest FrameWork,I tried the tutorial provided by Django Rest Framework, I'm new to django, I did the following.

**settings.py**

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'rest_framework',
        'books',
        'users',
    ]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from books.views import *
from users.views import *
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^books/all/$', all_books),
        url(r'^user/', get_user)
    ]

    urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns, allowed=['json', 'html','xml'])
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from books.serializers import *
from books.models import *

# Create your views here.

@api_view(['GET'])
def all_books(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    serializers = BookSerializer(books,many=True)
    return Response(serializers.data)
```

When I try to access the xml data, I Get this error by doing ?format=xml

```
{"detail":"Not found."}
```

the tutorial link http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get djangorestframework to return xml using format suffix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393330/how-do-you-get-djangorestframework-to-return-xml-using-format-suffix)

Comment: The answer is outdated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually your `settings.py` is missing the xml parser config.

1. install [rest_framework_xml](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#xml) : `pip install djangorestframework-xml`
2. Update INSTALLED_APPS in **settings.py**

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'rest_framework',
  'rest_framework_xml',
  'books',
  'users',
]
```

3. Add xml parser in **settings.py**:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_xml.parsers.XMLParser',
  ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_xml.renderers.XMLRenderer',
  ),
}
```

Comment: I got this error ImportError: Could not import 'rest_framework_xml.renderers.XMLRenderer' for API setting 'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES'. ImportError: No module named 'rest_framework_xml'.

Comment: you have to install `rest_framework_xml` as the error explains. I will update the answer to be a complete one.

Comment: did you follow my new update? you have to add it to the list of INSTALLED_APPS as mentioned above. It tested it locally and working with the config above.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting ImportError: No module named 'rest_framework_xml', but it's already installed and I added the 'rest_framework_xml'.

Comment: That's definitely weird. Check your environment.

Comment: I found out the problem, it worked, thank you very much for your great help.

Comment: According to documentation https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-xml/ 
you don't have to put 'rest_framework_xml' to settings.py

Answer (score 0):

It is adviceable that you use virtual environment. Check how to use pipenv [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/manage-python-environments-pipenv/)

Comment: This feels much more like a comment to the answer given than an actual answer to the question

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35029065)